npx create-react-app is not working with node v20.9.0
I used to create React apps with npx create-react-app but now I'm getting the following warning message:.
(node:6372) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 
11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

I read that's because node v20 no longer support that command and it's recommended to use next.js with npx create-next-app@latest.
Is there a way I can still use React without next.js or Expo?

If node v20 doesn't support that command, you can uninstall it and then install a lower version (probably 16 or 18) of node and try?


Is there a way i can still using react without next.js or expo?

As you can see Create React App have been removed from the official react documentation. The repository itself is not regularly updated anymore and at this point, we can consider it deprecated.
We see that react documentation now only list react framework like Next.js, remix, etc, as the recommended way to start new project with react.
But if you don't want to use any react framework, the react official team recommends you to use a bundler like vite or parcel.
The react community right now is lean towards vite, so you can just use it like for example:
npm create vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template react

